# Why is the Searing Smite spell not listed in the Roll20 spell list?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, roll20

Why is the *searing smite* spell not listed in the Roll20 [spell list](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Spells%20List#content)?

According to the [page for the spell on D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/searing-smite), it's listed in the PHB on page 274.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### The Roll20 spell list only includes those spells listed in the SRD.

The [D&D 5e SRD](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/systems-reference-document-srd) (System Reference Document) is essentially the free, publicly available version of D&D 5e.  It is a truncated version of the PHB that offers a reduced list of subclasses, spells, and basically everything else.

3rd party lists can only legally include spells that are available in the SRD. The spell Searing Smite is not included in the SRD, so it is not included in the Roll20 spell list.

For reference, here is the list of [spells available in the SRD](http://www.5esrd.com/spellcasting/spell-lists/), which should match up with those available on roll20.

Comment: [This filter on dndbeyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells?filter-class=0&filter-search=&filter-verbal=&filter-somatic=&filter-material=&filter-concentration=&filter-ritual=&filter-sub-class=&filter-source=1) also shows just the spells in the Basic Rules. Can also link to the [basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules) itself.

Comment: Roll20 [also direclty answers this](https://wiki.roll20.net/Compendium#.22Why_isn.27t_there_an_entry_for_.28Spell.2C_Rule.2C_Monster.2C_Etc..29_in_here.3F.22) if you'd like to add :)

Comment: This is also why, e.g., Roll20 only has one feat and one background available.

Comment: This answer could benefit from some clarification, since all of the D&D assets can be available in Roll20, they just require purchase of the appropriate sourcebook in the Roll20 format.